# When should I use multiple namespaces for multiple user roles in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I guess this is more of a conceptual question, but I usually just used `Devise` & `Decl_Auth` to manage user authentication and authorization respectively and specified different user roles.

The downside (or upside based on your perspective) to this is that at any one time - in any one browser - there can only be one user session (because User is the global namespace for all the roles).

However, I recently did a project with another Rails developer and he uses `Authlogic` for authentication - but he prefers splitting Admin & User roles into two namespaces. Here a User & Admin can be logged in to the app at the same time from the same browser in two different tabs.

What are the major benefits & disadvantages to both approaches and when would I want to do one over the other?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. What are the two ways? Namespacing and not namespacing?

Comment: Yes....you are correct. But specifically with relation to managing user authentication.

Answer (score 0):

U have different logic and different point of entrance in your system for admins and users ,so it is better to have separate namespaces for them, also it is a little bit secure.

The downside of that approach, that it will make your app logic a little bit tricky, but not so much.